# Play: How to validate a JSON where an attribute might be of diverse types?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I need a JSON structure that contains a name/value pair... and the value might be either a `String` or a `List[String]`:

```
{
  "name":"id",
  "value":"55e9cf3e0100003700dd2134"
}

{
  "name":"id",
  "value":["55e9cf3e0100003700dd2134","55e9e3430100004000d73b59"]
}
```

Here below is the class I use to deal with such a structure:

```
class NameValue protected(protected var json: JsValue) {

  def name = json as (__ \ 'name).read[String]
  def name_= (v: String) = setValue((__ \ 'name), Json.toJson(v))
  def value = json \ "value" match {
    case v: JsString => v.value
    case v => v.as[List[String]].head
  }
  def value_= (v: String) = setValue((__ \ 'value), Json.toJson(v))
  def multiValue = json \ "value" match {
    case v: JsString => List(v.value)
    case v => v.as[List[String]]
  }
  def multiValue_= (v: List[String]) = setValue((__ \ 'value), Json.toJson(v))
}
```

The `value` method returns

1. The value *as-is* in case of `String`
2. The first element in case of `List[String]`

The `multiValue` method returns

1. The value *as-is* in case of `List[String]`
2. A `List[String]` containing one element in case of `String`

Here below is the companion object that creates `NameValue` instances and validates its JSON:

```
object NameValue {

  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
  import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

  def apply(json: JsValue): JsResult[NameValue] = {
    validateNameValue.reads(json).fold(
      valid = { validated => JsSuccess(new NameValue(validated)) },
      invalid = { errors => JsError(errors) }
    ) 
  } 

  def apply(name: String, value: String): NameValue = new NameValue(
    nameValueWrites.writes(name, Some(value), None) 
  )  

  def apply(name: String, multiValue: List[String]): NameValue = new NameValue(
    nameValueWrites.writes(name, None, Some(multiValue)) 
  )   

  def unapply(nameValue: NameValue) = {
    if (nameValue eq null) None
    else {
      val multiValue = rameValue.multiValue
      Some((
        nameValue.name,
        if (multiValue.length > 1) multiValue else multiValue.head
      ))
    }
  }

  implicit val nameValueFormat = new Format[NameValue] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = NameValue(json)
    def writes(nameValue: NameValue) = nameValue.json
  }

  private val nameValueWrites = (
    (__ \ 'name).write[String] ~
    (__ \ 'value).writeNullable[String] ~
    (__ \ 'value).writeNullable[List[String]]
  ).tupled

  private val multiValue: Reads[JsArray] = {
    (__ \ 'value).json.pick[JsArray] andThen verifying[JsArray](_.value.nonEmpty)
  }

  val validateNameValue = (
    ((__ \ 'name).json.pickBranch) ~
    ((__ \ 'value).json.pickBranch)
  ).reduce

  // how do I integrate this in `validateNameValue`?
  val validateNameValue2 = (
    ((__ \ 'name).json.pickBranch) ~
    ((__ \ 'value).json.copyFrom(multiValue))
  ).reduce
}
```

Everything works fine... but I'd like to have just one validator regardless of whether the `value` attribute is a `String` or a `List[String]`. How do I create a single validator that replaces `validateNameValue` and `validateNameValue2`?

Comment: You seem to be kind of fighting the type system here and it's difficult to tell what you want to end up with. If you could have _either_ a list or a string, then the common denominator is a list, which may have a single element. That's easy to do with something like `path.read[Seq[T]].orElse(path.read[T].map(s => s.map(Seq(_))`. Would that suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate value into String and a list of String is not a good practice. A List can also contain a single element.

In addition, you can use *Json.format* to get rid of boilerplate code of defining reader and writer for a case class.

```
 import play.api.libs.json.Json

 object NameValue {
    implicit val format = Json.format[NameValue]
}
```